# Convert a clientsecret into a private key

Tags: google-app-engine, sha256, google-cloud-storage

I'm working with Google Cloud Storage in AppEngine and I'm attempting to use a POST form to upload a file to GCS.  The problem I'm having is with the steps needed to sign the policy document.  I can easily fetch the client_secret, which is a String from the `client_secrets.json` that the API Console gave me.  however, in order to create a signature, I need to convert that string into a `PrivateKey` object.  Here's what my code looks like:

```
//create the policy document and encode it
String policyDocument = ...  //omitted for brevity
String encodedPolicy = Base64.encodeString(policyDocument);

//sign using SHA256 with RSA
String secretKey = ... //I fetch this from client_secrets.json
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sig.initSign(secretKey); //THIS IS THE PROBLEM!  
sig.update(encodedPolicy.getBytes("UTF-8"));        
String signature = new String(Base64.encode(sig.sign()));

//put the values in the request attributes so we can fetch them from a JSP
req.setAttribute("policy", encodedPolicy);
req.setAttribute("signature", signature);
```

As noted above, my problem is in the line

```
sig.initSign(secretKey); //THIS IS THE PROBLEM!
```

`secretKey` is a String.  `Signature.initSign()` expects a `PrivateKey`, or one of its descendant objects.  How do I convert the string in the `client_secrets.json` into a PrivateKey (or derived) object that I can pass `Signature.initSign`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

OK, here's where I am right now.  I tried the suggestions below, and all of the documentation is urging me to use the client_secret in the client_secrets.json file downloaded from the Google API console, *not* the service account.  And besides, I'm trying to construct an example of a user's upload, not a service account.

I found the following code on another page:

```
public static String signPolicyDocument(String policyDocument, String secret) {     
try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        byte[] secretBytes = secret.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretBytes, "HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(signingKey);
        byte[] signedSecretBytes = mac.doFinal(policyDocument.getBytes());          
        return new String(Base64.encode(signedSecretBytes));
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

And it gets me all the way through the process...until I submit the resulting form.  Then I get the following response:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
```

What signing method is it looking for?

Comment: Are you using App Engine? The question does not mention it but it is labeled as such.

Comment: I am working in AppEngine.  I edited the OP to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a file to GCS from Appengine you can use the blobstore Api. Follow the steps described in [Using Blobstore with GCS](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#using-blobstore-with-gcs). The advantage is that you don't have to worry about keys and the code is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you need to do:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
sig.initSign(privateKey);
```

The `keyBytes` variable should contain a `byte[]` array with your [service account key file in it](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I found a couple of problems.  To begin with:

    sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment.  

so I tried to replace it with this:

    byte[] encodedKey = Base64.decode(key64);

Comment: That didn't work; it throws "Illegal character in Base64 encoded data."

so I omitted the decode step; I simply passed the key directly into the keyspec.  The result was
    java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : Detect premature EOF

Comment: You're right, you should use ``Base64.decode``. Are you using the "client_secret" field of client_secrets.json? It should be valid base64.

Comment: Yes, I'm using client_secret from client_secrets.json.  In a debugging window, I verified that the client_secret I pulled out of the json perfectly matches the client secret on the Google API Console.  And it `Base64.decode` still throws an exception when I pass in client_secret.

Comment: Just to make sure, I generated a new secret and updated client_secrets.json.  Now, `Base64.decode` executes without an exception, and I can pass the result into a keySpec.  but when I get to `keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);` I get the following error:
`java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : Detect premature EOF`

Comment: I've updated the question. I think you should be using a service account private key file, not the client_secrets.json.

Comment: I've edited the question at the top of the post to keep it up to date with where I am right now.

Answer (score 1):

The final answer to this problem is like the conclusion of Wargames.  As WOPR said, "A strange game...the only way to win is not to play."  Avoid signing and policy document and all that crap and use the blobstore.

(See this:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#using-blobstore-with-gcs)

It's very easy to implement; when you create your temporary blobstore upload URL like so:

```
    //open the blobstore service and create the upload url
    BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();        
    String uploadUrl = bs.createUploadUrl("/display",
            UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(bucket));
```

The downside to this approach is the object name will be a string of characters you don't recognize.  You can open the blobstore viewer and see your object by file name in the blobstore, but in GCS its object name will be gobbledygook.  (A hash, maybe?  A randomly assigned ID)?

Comment: What would make this approach perfect is if there would be a way to specify, in your code, which object name is used when the object is saved to GCS.  Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Still refining this approach.  A possible solution I found is to do this:

Comment: Still refining this approach.  A possible solution I found is to 
    1. upload the file
    2. capture the gobbledygook filename
    3. copy the gobbledygook filename to whatever filename you want
    4. delete the file with the gobbledygook name

To make a copy, what you do is issue a PUT request with a x-goog-copy-source header added to it:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#xgoogcopy

Comment: You probably know this by now, but for sake of posterity you can get a FileInfo object in the upload handler which has gs_object_name on it... https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass