# What is signature key in Authorization Authsub

Tags: google-app-engine, method-signature, authsub

I want to know what is the signature String in authorization of Google Authsub? I run this command  :

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -subj \
  '/C=US/ST=CA/L=Mountain View/CN=www.example.com' -keyout \
  myrsakey.pem -out /tmp/myrsacert.pem
```

It is creating two files:

- myrsakey.pem
- myrsacert.pem

I uploaded `myrsacert.pem` to this link https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomains
and now I have to pass signature string in my request.

myrsakey.pem file contain

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and myrsacert.pem file contains content

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now I want to know what is the value of string sig parameter when we signing securely Austhsub and getting session token. I am following this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub and in the last section I don't know what value to assign for sig parameter please someone help!

Comment: How to get private key ??

Comment: Note that you can always edit your question and update with more information.. for example to include the actual question.. no need to have it as a comment.. and also no need for begging for help here.. since by posting a question it means that you need help.. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a clientsecret into a private key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084452/convert-a-clientsecret-into-a-private-key)